# Resize para elementos e não janela do navegador

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, resize

Me ajudem numa dúvida rápida.

O resize do jquery identifica quando a janela do navegador é alterada e dispara um event. Até ai tudo bem.

Mas tem alguma forma de eu saber quando um elemento for alterado?
Quando mudar o tamanho dele?

Neste caso, o resize não me ajuda.
Algum help?

Comment: Depende de como é feito esse resize. Tem algum exemplo?

Comment: Sim claro. para janela é feito desta forma $(window).resize.... mas eu queria identificar uma alteração em um elento.. tipo $("#div-tal").resize... Mas não funciona pois o resize pelo que vejo é apenas para o window e não elementos.

Comment: não digo em disparar o evento... como é redimensionado o elemento?

Comment: É um campo do tipo textarea.. e gostaria de saber quando ele aumentar o height. Sempre que mudar o tamanho eu queria identificar que alterou para que eu possa disparar ações no layout. Quanto mais o usuário digitar e for aumentando.. eu disparo alterações.

Comment: o textarea não aumenta sozinho... tem algum plugin ou programação que faz isso?

Comment: Ele aumenta. Basta você ir no css e colocar resize auto e ele vai aumentando sozinho entende. E quando isso acontecer, eu quero identificar assim como numa window.

Comment: Vc que saber quando muda a largura width ou altura height? ou qualquer um dos dois?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o código abaixo que irá escutar qualquer alteração no `textarea` e executar o código que você quiser onde eu comentei `// faz alguma coisa aqui`:

> Incluí o `window resize` caso a `textarea` seja responsiva. Se for de largura  fixa, não precisa. Basta alterar esta linha `$(window, "textarea").on("input resize", function(){` para `ta_el.on("input", function(){`.

```
var ta_el = $("textarea");
var ta_width = ta_el.width();
var ta_height = ta_el.height();
$(window, "textarea").on("input resize", function(){
   if(ta_el.height() != ta_height || ta_el.width() != ta_width){
      ta_width = ta_el.width();
      ta_height = ta_el.height();
      console.log("tamanho do textarea alterado"); // apenas para visualizar, pode apagar esta linha
      // faz alguma coisa aqui
   }
});
```

**Um exemplo:**

```js
// função apenas para exemplificar. NÃO COPIE
function auto_grow(element) {
    element.style.height = "5px";
    element.style.height = (element.scrollHeight)+"px";
}

var ta_el = $("textarea");
    var ta_width = ta_el.width();
    var ta_height = ta_el.height();
    $(window, "textarea").on("input resize", function(){
       if(ta_el.height() != ta_height || ta_el.width() != ta_width){
          ta_width = ta_el.width();
          ta_height = ta_el.height();
          console.log("tamanho do textarea alterado"); // apenas para visualizar, pode apagar esta linha
          // faz alguma coisa aqui
       }
    });
```

```css
textarea {
    resize: none;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea oninput="auto_grow(this)"></textarea>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado. Era isso mesmo que eu estava procurando. O seu código me ajudou demais. Vlw. Não sabia que o window funcionava desta forma. Fico grato.

Comment: @DávilAndré Fico contente. Se puder marcar ✓ na resposta, isso é importante pra nós. Valew!